# Searching a value in a "piecewise" ordered array

Tags: algorithms, search-algorithms, arrays, binary-search

If we have an array $A$ of length $N$, which is partitioned into $\sqrt{N}$ adjacent subarrays $A(i)$, each of which is monotonically ordered from $\min(i)$ to $\max(i)$ (it is known what places have those bounds in A for each subarray), with the following conditions:

```
min(i) < min(i+1),
max(i) < max(i+1),
min(i+1) < max(i),
If subarrays A(i) and A(i+1) both have the j-th element, then A(i,j) < A(i+1,j),
The number of elements in subarray A(i) is strictly increasing with i
```

Would it be possible to search an element in the array $A$, in time $O((\log N)^k)$, for a positive $k$?  If yes how?

If not, what kind of minimal additional conditions would allow that?

Edit. The subarrays are not necessarily of equal length.
They are strictly increasing. The above stated conditions are always guaranteed.

What I have tried so far is to binary search them separately, but that is obviously going to be very inefficient.

[Note that this question has obviously nothing to do with the search of the min of max value in the array. And I am not interested in sorting the array. Just the mere search.]

Comment: What did you try?  Where did you get stuck?

Comment: So far i tried to search in the subarrays, but it seems way too inefficient. I'd like to have a global logarithmic search time. How could I achieve that ?

Comment: How inefficient?  Could you find a possibly non-constant $k$ that works?  I.e., depending on $N$.  Or, asked slightly differently, which running time did you get?

Comment: Of course I obviously get O(sqrt(N) log(N)).

Comment: What do you know about the adjacent subarrays?  Are they all of length $\sqrt{N}$?  Could they be of any length?  Are we guaranteed that all of the subarrays are monotonically increasing, or could each one be either monotonically increasing or decreasing (no promises, they might each be different)?  Are the subarrays guaranteed to be strictly increasing/decreasing (so no adjacent elements are equal)?  Please edit your question to make the problem statement more precise and to show us what you've tried.

Comment: Of course the question is not a duplicate. It has nothing to do with the search of a minimum. This is a search of an element. Just like when you search an ordered array through binary search.

Comment: I have also added 2 more conditions in case they can be helpful to reduce the search to logarithmic

Comment: You cannot do it better than $O(N)$ and your $O(\sqrt{N} \log{N})$ is just wrong analysis.

Comment: Why ? Mine are just SQRT(N) independent binary searches. Why would we require O(N) ? I expect to be able to lower the complexity to a power of logN, using the extra info.

Comment: Suppose you have just two sorted array of size $n$ how you can merge them together in better than $O(n)$, if you have some way to do this, then you can improve merge sort to $o(n \log{n})$, which is impossible.

Comment: Why do i need to merge them ? This is simply a search problem. Not sort. You are talking of a different problem.

Comment: I was actually thinking of a sort of "double" or "nested" binary search... but I have still to manage to visualize it.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri  I think the $O(\sqrt{N} \log N)$ is a fine analysis.  It is simply another way of writing $O(\sqrt{N} \log \sqrt{N})$.  There are at most $\sqrt{N}$ possible arrays to search in and each search takes $\log \sqrt{N}$ time.

Comment: I mistaken, I thought this is a sorting problem, I didn't read thorough question.

Comment: @Pål GD That's right. The sqrt() can be factored out of the log as 1/2 and essentially seen as part of the const in the O() definition, I think. A key fact should be that if A(i,j) is greater than the searched value, then the same holds for all A(i,j) with larger i's. And vice versa if A(i,j) is smaller. But still I can't visualize an effective way to use this info.

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible to do this with $O(\sqrt{N})$ comparisons, saving an $O(\log N)$ factor over the straightforward "binary search each subarray".

The last condition, that the lengths of the subarrays strictly increases, makes things messy.  The analysis of $M$ subarrays, each of length $M$, is easier and it should be straightforward to extend the method to increasing-length subarrays.
Note that $\log M = O(\log N)$.

Also complicating things are the strict inequalities; it is easier to work with non-strict inequalities (which are also more general).

Finally, the conditions ensure that in subarray $A(i)$, the first element $A(i,1)$ is the minimum value and the last element $A(i,M)$ is the maximum value, so there is no need to deal with these elements explicitly.  This yields the simplified problem

1. there are $M$ subarrays of equal length $M$, and
2. for all $i,j$

   - [monotonicity across subarrays] $A(i,j) \le A(i+1,j)$,
   - [adjacent subarrays overlap] $A(i+1,1) \le A(i,M)$, and
   - [monotonicity within subarrays] $A(i,j) \le A(i,j+1)$.

If there is $u$ such that $A(u,1) \le n < A(u+1,1)$,
then only the first $u$ subarrays need to be considered,
and similarly for $v$ such that $A(v-1,M) < n \le A(v,M)$ focuses attention on the last $v$ subarrays; together their intersection defines a set of subarrays that must contain $n$.  The rest of the subarrays can be ignored.
This preprocessing can be done in $O(\log N)$ steps.

Then $A(i,1) \le n \le A(i,M)$ is guaranteed for each remaining $i$ in the range $M-v+1$ to $u$, otherwise $n$ is not in the array.  For the remainder, suppose that the preprocessing did nothing, so $u=v=M$ (this is the worst case). Run binary search on the middle subarray $w=\lfloor M/2\rfloor$; this determines that $A(w,j) < n < A(w,j+1)$; (if equality holds then $n$ has been found).

By monotonicity across subarrays, $A(i,j) \le A(w,j) < n$ for all $i \le w$ and similarly $n < A(w,j+1) \le A(i,j+1)$ for all $i \ge w$.

Now we need to recursively search about half of the remaining elements, considering the two rectangular blocks $A(1,j+1)..A(w-1,M)$ and $A(w+1,1)..A(M,j)$ in turn.  There are $M$ calls to check a block, but successive calls receive exponentially smaller blocks to work with.  Amortising the work across calls, the total work is $O(\sqrt{N})$ steps as each leaf of the search tree only does a constant amount of work.  More precisely this relates to solving the recurrence [$f(n) = 2f(n/4) + \log n$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f%28n%29%20=%202f%28n/4%29%20%2b%20log%20n/log%202) for which $f(n) \in O(\sqrt{n})$.

So overall, $O(\sqrt{N})$ steps suffice.

Note that the overlap of adjacent subarrays may be of use when extending to increasing-length subarrays, or in improving the algorithm, but isn't used here.

As far as I can tell, $\Omega(\sqrt{N})$ is also a lower bound.  A handwaving argument is that in the worst case, when all the values are close except for a single missing value, that value could be hidden in any of the rows and each row must be examined at least once.

Comment: I think the critical point here is that "each leaf of the search tree only does a constant amount of work" unfortunately does not hold true. In fact the number of elements you will be searching in each block is also a function of N, and not a constant.  Practically, if we picture the subarrays one "on top of the other" (say like a pyramid) you are intuitively removing at each step either the top left "rectangle" or the bottom right "rectangle"...

Comment: ... Problem is that at each removal you create a new split in 2 parts, each of which has to be searched and each of which has a number of element which depends on N. So we only make the search process more complicate due to recursion, I think. Am I right ?

Comment: Problem is not recursion, but that the subsets you consider for search at each step depend on N and therefore they not not take constant time. (It's obvious they cannot take constant time, as, if so, they could not add up to N elements of A.) So you essentially end up with same complexity of my naive approach (but an algo more difficult to implement). I think.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with your recursion. I said that. I am instead saying that your time complexity unfortunately is not O(sqrt(N)), imho, but the same as a distinct search in the subarrays, O(sqrt(N)log(N)). This is due to the fact that at each recursion step, while you throw away about half of the elements, you, on the other hand, generate 2 new smaller "rectangular blocks" which *both* have to be examined and have a cardinality which is a (decreasing) fraction of N.

Comment: The solution to the recurrence $f(n) = 2f(n/4) + \log n$ is an expression that is $O(\sqrt{n})$.  Do you disagree that this characterizes the runtime of the algorithm?

Comment: Let's drop +logn of the "preprocessing", as we can assume that no "redundant" subarrays have been used. Your expression f(n)=2 f(n/4) seems fine to me, to express the recursion. The "base case", is a binary search in a subarray portion, whose cardinality is a fraction of N.

Comment: The $\log n$ in the recurrence is unrelated to preprocessing, but is an estimate of the time taken to do a binary search on the middle row.  As I wrote, preprocessing ends up quite small in comparison to the rest, so it can be ignored for worst-case analysis.

Comment: Ok I see, this is actually the point. Your "base case" is in any case a binary search, even if on a fraction of N. The conceptual problem is that the recursion does not essentially reduce the number of searches, but only the number of elements searched within the binary searches. Since these are in the log() argument they have no significant impact on the time, and considering the overhead of recursion, I think the "naive" version would even be in practice a faster implementation. What we really need and the challenge, is to drastically reduce the overall steps (the part "outside" the log).

Comment: As I stated, it seems to me that $\Omega(\sqrt{N})$ is a lower bound.  I don't have time right now to develop a full communication complexity reduction, but this seems eminently doable.